# ISSymbol1.run is not a function

Tags: javascript, scada

I'm using indusoft to create html pages.
From what I've tried to study, it doesn't require any additional work. Just save through the indusoft program. Coupled with various settings through IIS, just like this, it can work normally.

but i found a problem, I don't know how to fix it.
[image: Error in console]

Comment: So far, this screen shot only indicates things wrong with your JavaScript files, nothing about IIS. If you are learning new tools, try to get started from a working sample provided by the tool vendors.